# How to set number of cells to show in collectionView with RxSwift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, rx-swift

I want to show only 20 cells in my **collectionView** (or less if the count is less than 20). I found ways to do it with delegates/datasources, but my project is totally on RxSwift/RxCocoa, and l want to find alternative solution **with Rx**.

If you know the way to make it right with Rx, please, share :)

Comment: Please explain why `collectionView.rx.items` won't work for you. That's the obvious solution.

Answer (score 0):

from the example code of [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/main/RxCocoa/iOS/UICollectionView%2BRx.swift)

The simple case is that the `collectionView`'s dataSource is static

```
       // In RxSwift, cell's count = dataSource.elementArray.count
       let dataSource = Observable.just([
             1,
             2,
             3
         ])

         dataSource.bind(to: collectionView.rx.items) { (collectionView, row, element) in
            // cell configuration part
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! NumberCell
             cell.value?.text = "\(element) @ \(row)"
             return cell
         }
         .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

for general use:

the `collectionView`'s dataSource is variable, and has default data,

use `BehaviorSubject`

```
// change the arr to the array of the model you want
let arr =    [   1,
                 2,
                 3
             ]
// change the type of [Int] to the type of [the model you want]

// In RxSwift, cell's count = dataSource.elementArray.count
lazy var dataSource = BehaviorSubject<[Int]>(value: arr)

dataSource.bind(to: collectionView.rx.items) { (collectionView, row, element) in
                // cell configuration part
                // the same as above
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! NumberCell
                 cell.value?.text = "\(element) @ \(row)"
                 return cell
             }
             .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

If the dataSource varies,

```
// equals to collectionView.reloadData
dataSource.onNext(newArr)
```

The cell configuration part will be called automatically.